# Cannot reach website and cannot connect to corresponding server on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, ftp

since yesterday I try to login via FileZilla on a server for FTP upload on my MacBook with Sierra.

The server is not reachable with FileZilla and even not via SSH (Error: No route to host). Ping says also "Destination port not reachable".

Also the website is not accessible anymore on any browser, not on my MacBook, not on my wife's MacBook and not on our iPhones, but on my Windows PC.

When I turn off my WiFi on my iPhone and try to reach the website with 3G, it works!

And today I had access to the website again on all devices for a few minutes. Unfortunately, it was too short to log on to the server and make a FTP upload. And now once again nothing works as describe above.

Do you have any idea and know how I can fix that?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: [1] Is the Windows PC on the same wifi network as the Mac/iPhone devices when it works? [2] Is your target webserver a public server (would we able to reach it from our browsers or SSH)?   ---- As a general rule `no route to host` usually means the network is not reachable. [3] When your ping fails does it at least show you an IP address for your webserver? If so, the DNS resolve is not likely to be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Bit of a long shot but this could potentially be a DNS issue with the servers that you're using. Try updating the dns servers you're using on your macs to Google's (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Oliver! I have changed the dns servers to Google's now, but didn't help so far.

Comment: apologies in that case, I don't have a high enough rating to post a comment, only an answer. Haw long have you been logging onto this server previously and it has performed fine? Also, is it a server you are in control of?